# Why double double quotes make string run as function?

Tags: bash, smart-quotes

A  simple function receive two arguments and add `and` ,then print them.

```
function myprint(){ echo "$1 and $2";}
```

It works.

```
myprint  xx  yy
xx and yy
```

It is a string,bash parse it separately.

```
"myprint  xx  yy"
bash: myprint  xx  yy: command not found
```

Why double double quotes make  string  run as function?

```
""myprint  xx  yy""
xx and yy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "double double quotes" are in fact not nested. Two times a double quote is opened and closed right away.

```
""myprint  xx  yy""
^^                  this is one pair of quotes with empty content
                 ^^ this is anther pair with empty content
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   this is not quoted at all
```

In effect `""myprint` is the command named: the empty string concatenated with "myprint", this resolves to the `myprint` function; and the last argument is the string "yy" concatenated with the empty string.

So you get unquoted `myprint  xx  yy`. The whole original command behaves as such.